# clojure working with scipy and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, clojure, jython, data-science

Is there any good way to call python from clojure as a means of doing data science with scipy, numpy, scikit-learn, etc.

I know about implementations of clojure which run on python instead of java, but this doeesn't work for me, as I also need to call java libraries in my project. I also know about Jython, but I don't know of a clean way to use this with Clojure.

I want to use Clojure in my projects because I prefer it as a language, but I can't deny that Python has an incredible community, and some of the most beautiful, well-designed libraries around.

Comment: You may be able to get some of what you want from Clojure's [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) or or [Incanter](http://incanter.org/).  (I'm don't know much about scipy or numpy, so I can't make this into an official answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to get Jython to play well with both Clojure and numpy/scipy, you can use [Hy](http://docs.hylang.org/en/latest/). It is hosted on Python and it somewhat resembles Clojure.

If I really wanted to use numpy/scipy, I would write the backend in Python (or Hy), run it as a separate service. And if I really like ring for instance, or can't live without Instaparse, I would write a frontend in Clojure.

As an aside Python has [EDN](https://github.com/swaroopch/edn_format) libs. It would be an interesting project to integrate one of them in Hy, or write one from scratch.

Comment: This Hy thing is awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know this may be a bit much, but I wanted to ask if there was a good way to mix Clojure and Python machine learning tools. I like writing in clojure more, so most of my current machine learning stack is written in a combination of python/java, and I guess I was hoping there might be a good wrapper for the scipy/numpy functionality

Comment: I'm also looking for a way that I can write my own algorithms alongside scipy/numpy without giving up too much of the efficiency loss from using python.

Comment: Assuming you've found a nice bridge between Clojure/Java and Python/Scipy/Numpy... Wouldn't it be strange to do computations that mix Numpy stuff and the new algos you've written in Clojure? Going back and forth. Also if other developers were to work on this codebase, wouldn't they have a hard time following up with what's going on? Because even if you can put everything in a single repository, as far as I'm concerned you'd have two apps and two codebases. Because the (both cognitive & runtime) distance between Clojure & Numpy is a lot more than the distance between Java & Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Give the [`toolz` library a try, it's a functional standard library for Python that was designed to generally adhere to the API of the Clojure standard library](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz).

Apart from that, I'd encourage you to find the seams between your computations, and write individual tools in the Unix way in either Clojure or Python depending on which seems to fit that use case best. Serialize data between the tools, either as text/JSON through pipes or using a binary serialization format like Protobuf, which has standard APIs for both Java and Python.

If you had a gun to my head and told me to build Clojure/Python interop, I'd start with `py4j` and bridge the two languages through Java interfaces, using `implements` members in a Python class and `reify` on the Clojure side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Graal VM now. Although some large companies are using it in production, it's still early days. Here's an example of using Python from Clojure:

```
(.eval context "python" "
import time;
time.clock()
")
```

http://gigasquidsoftware.com/blog/2017/10/22/embedded-interop-between-clojure-r-and-python-with-graalvm/